# 9 be-Av on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, mourning-aveilus, tisha-bav

When 9 be-Av falls on Shabbos, it is moved to the following Sunday.

Are there any restrictions on Shabbos because of 9 be-Av (maybe tashmish is forbidden)?

Comment: This is really two separate questions. Per suggestions there, I'm splitting off the _havdala_ question to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18101. This leaves only the restrictions-on-_Shabas_ question here. I'm editing answers accordingly.

Comment: Also calendrically related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17883

Comment: Also important: the fast begins approximately one hour before Shabbos ends.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whether or not *tashmish* and other private acts of mourning remain forbidden on Shabbat Tisha b'Av is a difference of opinion between the Mechaber and the Rama in [Shulchan Aruch OC 554:19](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%93#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.99.D7.98) with the Mechaber permitting and the Rama forbidding. Some Achronim debate whether Ashkenazim can rely on the Mechaber in certain pressing circumstances so please CYLOR for a final ruling.

Comment: Also taking pleasure walks and visting friends I think should also not be done.

Comment: @sam http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18093/759