# Do the customs in regards to *Yud Av* apply to *Yud-Aleph Av* on a year when the fast is pushed off?

Tags: minhag, fast-days, nine-days, tisha-bav

I know that people have the custom (I don't know how universal it is), to keep a lot of the restrictions of the nine days until *Chatzos* on *Yud Av*, such as not eating meat or doing laundry.

This year *Tishah B'Av* falls out on *Shaboss*, which causes the fast to be postponed to Sunday (which is *Yud*). My question is do the above mentioned customs apply this year on *Yud-Aleph* or not at all?

Comment: Calendrically related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17695, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18101

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/94061/759

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Rama rules in OC 558 that the prohibitions on wine and meat remain in force for only the night of 11 Av. The Mishna Berura (sk 4) notes that this is meant to be specific, and the other prohibitions do not apply immediately following the fast.

Comment: I recall reading (can't remember where) that, lichvod the day, we also don't do laundry right after the fast. This site http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/946845/jewish/Tisha-bAv-on-Shabbat-or-Sunday.htm mentions "all the restrictions", but gives no source

Comment: @Dan It is very possible that other customs exist, but that doesn't seem to be the psak of the Mishna Berura