# What to do when tisha b'av is nidcheh (this year)?

Tags: meat, music, nine-days, tisha-bav, three-weeks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do the customs in regards to *Yud Av* apply to *Yud-Aleph Av* on a year when the fast is pushed off?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17883/do-the-customs-in-regards-to-yud-av-apply-to-yud-aleph-av-on-a-year-when-the)

If tisha b'av is nidcheh like it is this year when are you allowed to:
1 start swimming
2 eat meat products
3 listen to music
4 do laundry
5 and any of the other things that are assur during the nine days/three weeks

**PLEASE** give the source.

Comment: @DoubleAA i looked for this (trying to get an answer for myself) and i couldnt find this - thanks for telling me.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to CYLOR for a final ruling :)

Comment: Yup - always do.

Answer (score 0):

Everything right away except meat and wine. (Rama 559:1 and Mishna Brurah 559:4)

Comment: just checcked, its 558, not 559, Mishna Brurah says - you can't eat meat and wine, but you can get a haircut. doesnt say anything about music or shower or swim