# Source for a quote from the Chofetz Chayim

Tags: fast-days, chofetz-chaim, bittul-torah

A friend of mine told me a while back that he read somewhere that the Chofetz Chayim was quoted as saying that if he could, he would annul all rabbinic fasts, for in our lowly generation these fasts only lead to Bittul Torah and don't inspire Teshuva. It is more than likely that this is an exaggeration of the Chofetz Chayim's words or that it is completely fabricated entirely. If anybody happens to have a source for this saying I would be very grateful.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18093/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22923/759

Comment: Big Shkoyach! It makes a lot more sense in the context of not learning on Tisha Bav

Comment: Biur Halacha 571 says something similar about private fasting