# Havdallah after Tisha B'Av

Tags: halacha, tisha-bav, havdalah, motzei-shabbos

When Tisha B'Av immediately follows Shabbos (either because the 9th of Av is Shabbos or because the 9th of Av is Sunday), how and when do we make havdallah?

Comment: Calendrically related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17883, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17695

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from my shul newsletter

No havdala on cup, no besamim.

At 9:02pm or after, say "Baruch Hamavdil Ben Kodesh L'chol"
(not with brocha). Remove shoes. (We say brocha of "Borei
Meorei Haish" in shul.)

Sunday night; Havdala on cup. No candle or besamim. For
Havdala, one may use grape juice or wine.

Comment: What about in the Shoma Esrei on motzei shabbat?

Comment: Also, what about the paragraph hinei kel yeshuati?

Comment: while it isn't included in the newsletter, I would figure that the ata chonantanu is said on Saturday night and on Sunday night I would guess (guess) that one starts with hagafen.

Comment: @Daniel Attah Chonantanu is said as usual Saturday night and Shmoneh Esrei is still not repeated if forgotten (OC 294:3)

Comment: @Daniel according to my shul's bulletin, after the fast, "[o]nly the two blessings "borei p'ri hagafen" and "hamavdil" are recited. The introductory verses are omitted, as are the blessings over the spices and candle. "

Answer (score 7):

Havdalah is said Sunday night after the fast, omitting the blessings on spices and the flame (the latter of which is said on its own next to a flame on Saturday night). ([Shulchan Aruch OC 556](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%95#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90))

Attah Chonantanu is said as usual Saturday night and Shmoneh Esrei is still not repeated if forgotten ([OC 294:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=141))

Comment: Moved from http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/17702/revisions