# Taanis Chalom on shabbos when a fast day is pushed off

Tags: halacha, shabbat, fast-days, dream

If a fast day which normally falls out on shabbos is pushed off, such as the 17th of Tammuz, and a person fasts on that shabbos for another permissible reason, such as a taanis chalom (fast for having a bad dream) is that person exempt from fasting the following day - ie the nid'che 17th of Tammuz fast?

Comment: possibly related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17702/759

Answer (score 1):

The Ben Ish Chai in Rav Pealim (chelek alef question 29) cites the masat binyamin among others as indicating that you would have to fast on 17 Tammuz because anyway a person is obligated to fast a second time for having violated oneg shabbos by fasting on shabbos - even though he is permitted to fast for a tanit halom. See Orah Hayim 288

Comment: Does the make up fast need to be the next day?

Comment: @DoubleAA unclear, b'pashtus not but it is preferable to perform the make-up fast as soon thereafter as possible. I believe these factors contributed to the psak but cannot say for sure.